# How do I configure VS Code to debug code in a vagrant container?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vagrant, pyramid

I am working on a new python/pyramid web application and I am having difficulty setting up VS Code to debug python code in a vagrant container. Apparently, this is possible with pycharm, but I would prefer to use VS Code. The remote debugging docs haven't been too helpful. If anyone has experience or pointers on how to do this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope. Just learned how to use pdb inside the container. Not ideal but it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**My Environment**

Windows 10, and I am running Ubuntu 16.04 inside Virtualbox with Vagrant.  After I do `vagrant up` to start Virtualbox/Ubuntu, among the messages Vagrant provides is the SSH username and SSH address (in my case `vagrant` and `127.0.0.1:2222` respectively).  Ensure that you have an SSH **client** other than putty set up (I have Openssh - it's available on the Windows store and is typically installed at C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe).

First, install the *Remote Development* extension into VS Code.  Then push F1, type *remote* to bring up the remote development choices, and choose *Remote-SSH: Connect to Host...*

***A Problem***

Vagrant defaults to forwarding port 22 to 2222, and this seems to be a problem for VS Code.  I can ssh into Virtualbox/Vagrant fine with both git-bash and at the Windows command line (which uses Openssh) with the SSH Username and Address (above) by typing `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222` (note that `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222` will NOT work).  However, if you type this into VS Code to connect to the host, it will not work - it won't connect when a port is specified with `-p`.

***Solution***

If you are using Virtualbox with Vagrant, open the VirtualBox GUI and open the Settings for your running VM.  Click the Network item and then the appropriate Adapter.  Click Advanced and then click the Port Forwarding button.  Change the 2222 to 22 (i.e. you're just forwarding port 22 to 22 - you can make this change permanent in the Vagrantfile with `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 22`) and then exit the Settings.

***Now connect...***

After you've changed the port forwarding so that Virtualbox is listening on the default SSH port of 22, then you can connect from VS Code with just `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1`.

***One more thing...***

In VS Code hit F1, type *remote* and choose *Remote-SSH: Settings*.  At the bottom of remote settings, turn on *Show Login Terminal*.  (This is where you will type the password to complete the SSH login [default password is *vagrant*]).  I have not yet set things up for key-based login.  Maybe I'll update this answer when I do.

***Postscript***

Looks like it's still pretty involved to set up [remote debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_remote-debugging) at this point.

Comment: VScode now supports passing the port, i.e. `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222`